# zend framework 2 with db oracle

Tags: php, oracle, zend-framework2, php-extension

I use xamppv3.2.2
  use PHP Version 5.6.14 
  use windows 8.1
  use zend framework 2

I try to connect to Oracle DB(in other remote machine)

I can try set environment variables.

but i obtain always same error message:

> Zend\Db\Adapter\Exception\RuntimeException
>
> File:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\zendframework\zend-db\src\Adapter\Driver\Oci8\Oci8.php:149
>
> "The Oci8 extension is required for this adapter but the extension is
>   not loaded"

Please Help me

Thanks

Comment: You don't have oracle extension configured in your `php.ini`.

Comment: yes i set "extension=php_oci8.dll" in my php.ini, but i obtain the same error

Comment: do you have `oracle db server` installed?

Comment: no, i have Sql Developer for view data in db, the oracle db is remote

Comment: than why don't you use `PDO` or `mysqli_` extensions

Comment: great Idea! - i use PDO_OCI and PHP and i can connect!! Now I try to do it with zf2 =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to use `PDO` extension. Or use `mysqli` extension. Learn more about it at
[Php PDO extension](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php).

Test Code:

```
$param = $_POST;
$db_username = "youusername";
$db_password = "yourpassword";
$db = "oci:dbname=yoursid";
$conn = new PDO($db,$db_username,$db_password);
$name = $param['module'];
$file = $param['file'];
$stmt = $conn->exec("INSERT INTO AL_MODULE (AL_MODULENAME, AL_MODULEFILE) VALUES ('$name', '$file')");
```

Comment: great Idea! - i use PDO_OCI and PHP and i can connect!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the Oci8 extension for PHP. Normally you just need to change the row `;extension=php_oci8.dll` in your php.ini to `extension=php_oci8.dll` and restart your server.

Complete installation instructions can be found here
http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php

Answer (score 0):

i use:

```
'db2' => array(
'driver'    => 'Pdo',
'dsn'   => 'oci:dbname=(DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
        (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = *.com)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
        (SERVICE_NAME = aprx)
    ))',
'username'      => 'yourUser', 
'password'      => 'yourPass',
'platform_options' => array('quote_identifiers' => false)
),
```

Important i set:
'platform_options' => array('quote_identifiers' => false)
for use sql query on dbOracle

Thanks for your help @mega6382